# Gulp task not working on template string writing style

Tags: gulp

I just running my gulp task recently, but when try running a task such as sass, it didn't affect anything to the file source. Actually the task is running on CLI, but nothing changes. I'm using templating style to my function, and if I change it to a normal writing path(src/../..), the task is running well. Can somebody explain this, please?

```
const sourceAssetsCss = 'src/assets/css';
const sourceAssetsScss = 'src/assets/scss';

***// Compile SCSS to CSS src developer***
function sassRun() {
    var prefix = [autoprefixer({
        overrideBrowserslist: ['last 3 version']
    })];
    return gulp
        .src(sourceAssetsScss + '/*scss')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(sass({
            outputStyle: 'nested'
        }).on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(postcss(prefix))
        .pipe(plumber.stop())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(`${sourceAssetsCss}`))
        .pipe(notify('sass successfully compiled'));
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `sourceAssetsScss + '/*.scss'`?  Note the dot before `scss`.

Comment: Sorry, I guess it's working now. I just figure it out and found that my root folder is changed somehow. Thank you for your help